# How do I map four Cortex M0 physical addresses to a single array for bit banging?

Tags: cortex-m

In my Cortex M0 design, I have some old hardware which went through many updates and has 128 unit_enable bits which are allocated to four physical registers at address 0x40000000 + 4*[0, 9, 18, 20]. 
In my firmware I would like to use a unit_enable[128] to address each of the bits for R/W as if it were an array. I went through some of the ARM documentation but no avail. 
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

> The ARM Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M0+ processors do not have the bit band
>   feature. It is possible to use a bus wrapper to add the bit band
>   feature to the Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M0+ processors. In this case, the
>   bus wrapper must retain correct memory ordering.

[Sources](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHBIHDF.html)

The Cortex-M System Design Kit (CMSDK) includes an example of module, the AHB bit-band wrapper ([cmsdk_ahb_bitband.v](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0479c/I1020077.html)), which provides the bit-band functionality for the Cortex-M0 and Cortex-M0+ processor.

However this SDK is intended for chip designers and FPGA designers working with the Cortex M processors.